# One box is one pixel wider but has same class

Tags: css, class, html, pixel

I have four boxes in a row and they all have the same class. They all should be the same width but one is 1 pixel wider than the rest and it's throwing the row out. As far as I can see, the content is not pushing it, and there is nothing in the box to make it 1 pixel wider. It's the second last box to the right with the contact form in it on this site: http://www.guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/
If it's not content, how can I tell what's making this particular div 1 pixel wider than the rest?

I had compensated for the border in the widths of each box: layout is 1120px wide. 1120/4 = 280. Each box has a padding of 5px, so thats 5 on the left and right. 280-10=270. Then the border, which is 1px on each side, so thats 270-2 = 268. I have set my class for the boxes to be 268px wide and yet one is one pixel wider. I don't really want to sacrifice the border (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `border: 1px solid #111111;` on line 247 of `global.css`.

So if you are aware of [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

[image: CSS Box Model]

The `border` is counted outside of the element and not inside hence it offsets your element by `2px` and not <s>`1px`</s> because it takes `1px` on the `left`, `1px` on the `right` as well as `top` and `bottom` too.

So two solutions here, either you can use `border: 0;` or you need to use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) on that element, which will count the `border` inside instead of outside.

Comment: I had compensated for the border in the widths of each box:
layout is 1120px wide.
1120/4 = 280.

Each box has a padding of 5px, so thats 5 on the left and right. 
280-10=270.

Then the border, which is 1px on each side, so thats
270-2 = 268.

I have set my class for the boxes to be 268px wide and yet one is one pixel wider.
I don't really want to sacrifice the border (yet).

Comment: @Ellouise your element is `1120px` (`desktop.css` - `#main_nav` - Line 47) wide + `1px` `border` makes it `1122px`

Comment: taking the border off #main_nav didn't fix it.

Comment: The box-sizing method works, but is it compatible with internet explorer?

Comment: @Ellouise not the old versions - http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing, also, getting rid of the border on line 247 global.css works for me

Comment: I ended up using the box-sizing method and taking the border away for users with ie8 and under. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

That extra space is coming because of border. So you need to set it to zero.

Declare `border: none;` for the last box and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your class

```
border: none;
outline: none;
width:0;
```

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the border.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the css border property to that div

```
border:0px;
```

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the border.